# How to filter data from local Json file using search bar

Tags: json, swift, filter, searchbar

I have a local json file, and I already loaded it to my project. The data in json file looks like this:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "hanzi":  "安全", "pinyin": "ān quán", "imageName": "a"},
    {"id": 2, "hanzi": "安静", "pinyin": "ān jìng", "imageName": "b"},
    {"id": 3, "hanzi": "帮助", "pinyin": "bāng zhù", "imageName": "c"},
    {"id": 4, "hanzi": "白天", "pinyin": "bán tiān", "imageName": "d"},
    {"id": 5, "hanzi": "摆", "pinyin": "bǎi","imageName": "e"}
]
```

I created VocabList.swift to display the data using NavigationView. Now I would like to add a search bar to be able to search the data with two different keys--"hanzi" and "pinyin".

I followed the tutorial online and created Searchbar.swift. I can call it in VocabList.swift with no problem, but when I tried to define the filter, it reported an error "Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type".

Here is the Searchbar.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate{

        @Binding var text: String
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

            text = searchText
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame:.zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

Here is the VocabList.swift:

```
@State private var searchTerm: String = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)

            List(vocabData.filter{
            ($0["hanzi"] as! String).range(of: searchTerm!) != nil ||
            ($0["pinyin"] as! String).range(of: searchTerm!) != nil
            })
            { vocab in
                NavigationLink(destination: VocabDetail(vocab: vocab)) {
                    VocabRow(vocab: vocab)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Vocab"))
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to coding. I don't know where went wrong. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Modify "searchBar - textDidChange" method in Coordinator class as mentioned below

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // filteredData here is the result, data is the local array
    filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
        // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
        return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
    // Reload UI element as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: Thanks Komal Gupta! I modified my code as you said, and also made a few changes according to my project. But it give me another error:"Instance member 'filteredData' of type 'SearchBar' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'SearchBar.Coordinator'".  The thing is my JSON file is not from the internet, it's a local file.

Comment: "data" is the local array and "filteredData" is the resulting array of type [String]. I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks! I My “data” is loaded this way: “let vocabData: [Vocab] = load(“VocabData.json”). In my SearchBar.swift, I defined that “var filteredData = [String]( )”, and also changed “data: data. filter” to “Vocab: Vocab.filter”. But it still gave me the same error .Can you check what’s the issue here?         Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please let me know what error are you seeing in the debugger

Comment: I got two errors. The 1st one is the original one in VocabList.swift which is  "Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type". The 2nd one is at SearchBar.swift which is "Instance member 'filteredData' of type 'SearchBar' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'SearchBar.Coordinator'".